# Wordpress function tag coming outside the table

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a table of data in wordpress...

in the following code...

```
echo '<tr><td>Category</td><td>:</td><td>'. the_category(', ') .'</td></tr>';
```

category name is not displaying in correct position, it is displaying above all the row...

i can't figure out the problem... everything seems perfect...

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_the_category_list(', ')`. [See documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category_list).

`get_the_category_list()` returns the result, `the_category()` prints the result

Answer (score 0):

Well that is something that `echo` will do with functions that print result you should use it like this

```
<?php // some code ?>
<tr><td>Category</td><td>:</td><td><?php the_category(', ') ?></td></tr>
<?php // some code ?>
```

Use functions in html.